# Copying data from one entry into a new entry in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, sharepoint-list

I wonder if you could help.  I'm trying to create a log (of sorts) using a SharePoint list (i know it may not be the best option out there however its what i've been give lol).  One of the things that the powers that be want is a handover element - however this only gets filled in twice a day at shift change.

Is there a way of copying the data from the previous days handover into the current day?  Will point out that various entries would happen in between.  The first handover would be between approximately 1300-1330hrs and the second handover anytime after 1700hrs

I was possibly thinking of using a flow but wasn't quite sure where to start - if even its at all possible.

A couple of things, i'm using SharePoint Online and its a government tenant so limited to what i can do (ie sharepoint designer/coding etc etc)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could build a scheduled cloud flow to copy data regularly.
[image]

Comment: And could this be started on the selection of a option box at all Emily when the entry is created?